# html2canvas + FileSaver browser issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas, filesaver.js

I'm currently working with html2canvas and FileSaver, to save the generated canvas when the button is clicked. A dialog will popup and the user can choose where to save the image and rename it if they wish. It works perfectly... in Firefox. I can't seem to get it to work in either Chrome, IE, or Safari.

The html2canvas will do its part, and create the image out of the div in all of those browsers. The FileSaver dialog box is the thing that will not work in the aforementioned browsers.

Any ideas? I've attached my script. You can see my full working code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ticklishoctopus/556etja4/

Script (with some help from previous SO posts):

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
       html2canvas($("#testbtn"), {
           onrendered: function (canvas) {
               theCanvas = canvas;
               document.body.appendChild(canvas);

               canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
                   saveAs(blob, "testimage.jpg");
               });
            }
         });
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Realised toBlob is not supported in Chrome. Use this instead:
[Possible Solution](https://github.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js)

Comment: I'll give this a go! Will I need to change anything in my script? Or just import this library?

Comment: read the description. You might need to change your standard functions with the required ones from the library.

Comment: We must be reading different things, I'm seeing this: "canvas-toBlob.js implements the standard HTML5 canvas.toBlob() and canvas.toBlobHD() methods in browsers that do not natively support it. canvas-toBlob.js requires Blob support to function, which is not present in all browsers. Blob.js is a cross-browser Blob implementation that solves this."

Which has no real answer.